# Oracle query returning error single-row subquery returns not executing

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I am trying to retrieve a result set which returns the overall space consumed vs total space per day and per week break down by database schemas only for tables , unfortunately i am returning into error

please advise whether it is realistically possible to acheive this using the below query ?

**Query**

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT MIN(CREATION_TIME) FROM V$DATAFILE) "CREATE_TIME",
    (SELECT DISTINCT OWNER FROM DBA_SEGMENTS WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE' ) "SCHEMAS",
    (SELECT NAME FROM V$DATABASE) "DATABASE NAME",
    ROUND((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024 ),2) || 'TB' "DATABASE_SIZE",
    ROUND((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  ) - ROUND(FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  ),2) || 'TB' "USED_SPACE",
    ROUND(((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  ) - (FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  )) / ROUND(SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  ,2)*100,2) || '%TB' "USED_IN%",
    ROUND((FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  ),2) || 'TB' "FREE_SPACE",
    ROUND(((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  ) - ((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  ) - ROUND(FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024  )))/ROUND(SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/ 1024/ 1024 ,2 )*100,2) || '%TB' "FREE_IN %",
    ROUND(((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/1024 ) - (FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/1024 ))/(SELECT SYSDATE-MIN(CREATION_TIME) FROM V$DATAFILE),2) || 'GB' "GROWTH_DAY",
    ROUND(((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/1024 ) - (FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/1024 ))/(SELECT SYSDATE-MIN(CREATION_TIME) FROM V$DATAFILE)/ROUND((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/1024 ),2)*100,3) || '%GB' "GROWTH_DAY_IN%",
    ROUND(((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/1024 ) - (FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/1024 ))/(SELECT SYSDATE-MIN(CREATION_TIME) FROM V$DATAFILE)*7,2) || 'GB' "GROWTH WEEK",
    ROUND((((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/1024 ) - (FREE.P / 1024 / 1024/1024 ))/(SELECT SYSDATE-MIN(CREATION_TIME) FROM V$DATAFILE)/ROUND((SUM(USED.BYTES) / 1024 / 1024/1024 ),2)*100)*7,3) || '%GB' "GROWTH WEEK IN %"
FROM (
    SELECT BYTES FROM V$DATAFILE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BYTES FROM V$TEMPFILE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT BYTES FROM V$LOG
) USED
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT SUM(BYTES) AS P FROM DBA_FREE_SPACE) FREE
GROUP BY FREE.P;
```

**Error**

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

could you please also suggest whether is is good option to use DBA_SEGMENTS table or DBA_OBJECTS ?

Comment: Why are you not using normal joins, instead of these subqueries? The subqueries are not correlated to the outer query, so may return any number of rows. And using `,` instead of `CROSS JOIN` is deprecated

Comment: @Charlieface - can you edit the query to have the cross joins ?

Comment: @Charlieface - same error

Comment: I never said that would fix it, that was just the old-fashioned cross join syntax. Your issue is the subqueries `SCHEMAS` and `DATABASE` (as well as `SYSDATE-MIN(CREATION_TIME)` one) returning multiple results. I can't fix that because I have no idea how you want to correlate the inner table to the outer. My comment before was that if you would use a regular join, it would force you to think about how to match the rows up

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, this is a problem:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT OWNER FROM DBA_SEGMENTS WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE' ) "SCHEMAS",
```

This can return more than one row.

You should really debug your code to find where the problem is.  Clearly, the subqueries with `SUM()` and no `GROUP BY` return only one row, so they are not a problem.

Comment: If i filter on one schema it returns but if i want to return all the schemas i encounter the above error, how to resolve this query ?